# facebook login with multiple users

Tags: ios, facebook

I have integrate facebook api and i easily login but after logout my app from Facebook when i again login then is shows you have already authorised and come to the app home page.But I want if I logout account then next time again require username and password to use the different user.

I already yes ,status and review option from Facebook developers account to live but yet this problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your logout is fine I think  you are not clear the current session of facebook, when you click the logout button You have to implement the two methods for  logout.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[loginManager logOut];
```

set  the currentAccessToken to nil

```
[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
[FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];
```

for loginview

```
- (void)loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton { 

   // do like delete the permission, this means you fully logout from facebook

    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions/"
   parameters:nil
   HTTPMethod:@"DELETE"]
startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"deleted successfully");
}];


    }
```

the above method clear the current session , when you click the facebook button again it ask the new permission for new user.

if you want to clear the safari cookies also use

Only clears the local FB session information but not the Safari cookies. So, after I log in the user, I clear the Safari cookies:

```
NSLog(@"Logged out facebook");
 NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
 NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies])
 {
NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
if(domainRange.length > 0)
{
   [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
}
```

if you want to access the multiple user in the same time see sample app name  **Scrumptious** you can get this app from [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples)

Comment: I got this error when i add fbsdkaccess token and fbsdkprofile.. Definition of 'FBSDKAccessToken' must be imported from module 'FBSDKCoreKit.FBSDKAccessToken' before it is required.I already import correct,/

Comment: - (void)loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
{
    FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [loginManager logOut];
    [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
    [FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];
   }
i use this code for logout from Facebook.

Comment: ya correct are your tried that , if you not get the ansewr check the updated answer

Comment: what the issue u faced bro

Comment: when again login then not a new window for new user ..it again jump to home.

Comment: yaa i update every thing ..which you told me but ..still.......no  issue solved..